# TSQL: Selecting parent based on conditions on child

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016, database-performance

I have a parent table `Orders` and a Child table `Jobs` with the following sample data
[image]

I want to select Orders based on the following requirements

1>For each order there may be 0 or more jobs. Do not select order if it does not have any job.
2>A user cannot work on more than one job that belongs to the same order.
For example User `1` cannot work on the Jobs that belongs to Order 1 and 2 because he already worked on jobs `1` and `4` from the same order.
3>Only select orders that have jobs in `Requested` status

I have the following query that gives me expected result

```
DECLARE @UserID INT = 2

SELECT O.OrderID
FROM Orders O
JOIN Jobs J ON J.OrderID = O.OrderID
WHERE 
J.JobStatus = 'Requested' AND
NOT EXISTS
(  
    --Must not have worked this Order
    SELECT 1 FROM Jobs J1
    WHERE J1.OrderID = O.OrderID AND J1.UserID = @UserID
)
Group By o.OrderID
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f2482/12)

Query joins the `Jobs` table twice. I am trying to optimize query and looking for a way to achieve the expected result by using `Jobs` table only once if possible.  Any other solution is also appreciated. I can alter the table schema if required.

The jobs table has almost 20M rows and some time query shows poor performance. (Yes, we looked at indexes). I think its scanning jobs table twice causing the performance issue.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: When asking performance questions, an execution plan (using Paste The Plan) is normally required.

Answer (score 1):

If the aim is just to "use Jobs table only once", I would try something like:

```
DECLARE @UserID INT = 2
    
SELECT 
    O.OrderID
FROM 
    Orders O
    INNER JOIN Jobs J ON J.OrderID = O.OrderID  
GROUP BY
    O.OrderID
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN J.JobStatus = 'Requested' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
    AND SUM(CASE WHEN J.UserID = @UserId THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f2482/16)

To optimize further, I would suggest replacing the `varchar` datatype of the `JobStatus` column with `tinyint` one (and create a `JobStatuses` table). Once your `Job` table has 20M records, then `varchar(10)` gives you 190 Mb, however using the `tinyint` reduces the column size to 19 Mb — this gives you less IO-Read operations.

And I would try to separate the child filtering from joining it with the parents. Such approach may use less memory for a single operation and win in performance because of that:

```
DECLARE @UserID INT = 2
DECLARE @OrderIDs TABLE (OrderID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)

INSERT INTO @OrderIDs
SELECT
    OrderID
FROM
    Jobs
GROUP BY
    OrderID
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN JobStatus = 'Requested' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
    AND SUM(CASE WHEN UserID = @UserId THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0

SELECT
    O.*
FROM
    Orders O
    INNER JOIN @OrderIDs ids on ids.OrderID = O.OrderID
```

Comment: The job status is actually `ID` of type int. Just for understanding purpose I kept it as nvarchar

Comment: With this approach look like I don't even have to join with Orders table. I can directly use Jobs table to get OrderID

Answer (score 0):

You might consider adding the following index to the `Jobs` table:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx_jobs ON Jobs (OrderID, UserID, JobStatus);
```

This index, if used, should speed up the not exists subquery in your query above.  Also, it can be used for the join from `Orders` to `Jobs` in the outer top level query (although SQL Server would probably have to do an index scan).